# Eloquent pivot table with different column name

Tags: php, eloquent

Users table

```
- id
- name (string)
```

Visits table

```
- id
- user_id
- viewer_id
```

I want to get a list of visits with the linked username for a given user (in this case id = 1)

```
$visits = \Visits::where(['user_id' => 1])->with('user')->get();
```

this is my visits model:

```
class Visits extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'visits';

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $visits = new Visits;
        $visits->save();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'viewer_id');
    }

}
```

this is my User model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->save();
    }

}
```

it returns the data but the "user" is *null*

Comment: Is it `visitor_id` or `viewer_id`?

Comment: viewer_id *my bad updating description right now*

Comment: `viewer_id` is *not* `null`, right?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir correct. is never null. that's the id of the user that visited the profile of other user. :)

Comment: Have you looked at the executed queries?

Comment: try `belongsTo(App\User::class, 'viewer_id')`

Comment: didn´t work. error 500. then I changed it to return $this->belongsTo(\User::class, 'viewer_id'); but is still returning user: null

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to change your code a little bit. Please try the following:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'viewer_id', 'id');
}

$visits = \Visits::where(['user_id' => 1])->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: Please make sure your model name is "User".

Comment: still null for user. yes the model is User

Comment: Can you share visits table data here? Does it has proper value of viewer_id?

Comment: How you are accessing the user? You need to access it directly i.e. $visit->user not $visit->user(). Pleaee provide the code for your view file.

Comment: I´m doing $visits = \Visits::where(['user_id' => 1])->with('user')->get(); and it returns all the visits but the user is null. the two models and the table structure I have is in the description

Comment: I was actually doing $visits = \Visits::where(['user_id' => 1])->with('user')->get('id'); and that´s why it wasnt returning the user apparently you have to do ->get() to get the user. is there a way to restrict the fields on user? I just want to display the id of the visit and the username of User

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, in your `visits table`, `user_id` is the person who has been visited and `viewer_id` are the persons/users who have visited.

So, my `Visits` model would have been something like this

```
class Visits extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'visits';
    protected $fillable = array('user_id','viewer_id'); //Fillable is for Mass Assignment


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }

   public function visitorsDetails(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'viewer_id','id');
   }   
}
```

Now for getting all the visitors detail for user with `user_id=1`, I would do something like this.

```
$visitorList = Visits::where('user_id',1)->with('visitorsDetails')->get();
echo <pre>;
print_r($visitorList->toArray()); // This will show the visitor with visitors detail in an array form.
```

**Note:** I am not sure why you are writing `store` function inside modal, it is not required you can directly save data from the controller itself.